# $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \equiv 0 \mod p \implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}^{p} \equiv 0 \mod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm a lay at modular arithmetic, but while solving another problem this 'appeared' to me, so I wanted to know if it's correct.

Starting with simpler cases:

**Note**: $p$ is a prime number and all equivalences are taken modulo $p$

- Case $1$: $n = 2$

We want to prove that $a_1^p + a_2^p \equiv 0$.

From the assumption that $a_1 + a_2 \equiv 0 \implies a_1 \equiv -a_2 \implies a_1^p \equiv (-a_2)^p \implies a^p-(-a_2)^p \equiv 0$ . So it works for all odd primes.

- Case $2$: $n = 3$

We want to prove that $a_1^p + a_2^p + a_3^p \equiv 0.$

As $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \equiv 0 \implies a_1 + a_2 \equiv -a_3 \implies (a_1 + a_2)^p \equiv (-a_3)^p.$ By [Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) and transitivity, we have that $a_1^p + a_2^p - (-a_3^p) \equiv 0$. Again, it works for odd primes.

Therefore, looks like it works for all $n$ (not going to try proving by induction). Is the proof right?

Comment: See [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) which states, for all primes $p$, that $a\equiv a^p\pmod{p}$ for *all* integers $a$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oh, that's right, thanks! So you sum each congruence and get the above case, correct? $a_1 \equiv a_1^p \mod p, a_2 \equiv a_2^p \mod p \implies a_1 + a_2 \equiv a_1^p + a_2^p \mod p$ and so on...

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you're correct that you can sum each congruence to get the above case. Somewhat more succinctly, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\equiv\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p\pmod{p}$ for *all* integers $a_i$ and non-negative integers $n$, regardless of what their particular sum is congruent to. In your particular case, since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ as well.